# Ubuntu One Android - could not get volume

Tags: android

Everytime I refresh my data in the ubuntu one app for android i get a message "Error: could not get Volume. Ressource not found."
What can i do?

Thanks

Comment: Anyone who is affected by this can head over to Launchpad and click at the top of the page on the green line "This bug affects 1 person. Does this bug affect you?": http://launchpad.net/bugs/1019883 If you can provide further information (than beeing affected) please add a comment to the report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will release the fix shortly, sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Thank you very much, the Update today solved this problem and it works great! Thanks!

Comment: You are most welcome :)